# Getting wrong screen height when trigger orientationchange event

Tags: javascript, mobile

I wrote the code below to check my mobile screen height when I rotate it to `Portrait` or `Landscape`.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  rotateScreen();
}, false);

function rotateScreen() {
  alert(window.orientation)
  alert($(window).height())
}
```

When I rotate it to `Portrait`, I get 0, 294. When I rotate it to `Landscape`, I get 90, 419. The figure is reversed, I have tried to wrap it in `$(document).ready()` but it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($(window).height())
})
```

It looks like that when I rotate the mobile to `Portrait`, I get the height of `Landscape`, and when I rotate the mobile to `Landscape`, I get the height of `Portrait`. Can someone suggest how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the effect of this code? http://jsfiddle.net/pAm62/1/

Comment: i am also running into this same problem. has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: @Dan Kanze Please try my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mobile viewport height after orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452349/mobile-viewport-height-after-orientation-change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding setTimeout could solve the problem, please try the code below:

```
function rotateScreen() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
       alert(window.orientation)
       alert($(window).height())
    }, 500);

}
```

Comment: I believe this is a cheap hack and you can't guarantee that it's going to happen. Also it will appear slow when it's quicker. The answer by Andy Polhill is a much better solution as it guarantees both at the right time.

Comment: @DominicWatson the problem with Andy solution is that it triggers before the resize animation ends (and shows the browser address bar on both iOS and Android) - so it gives a bigger innerHeight than supposed. And adding logic for that ends up being as cumbersome if not worse than the timeout.

Answer (score 11):

The **resize** event gets triggered after the **orientationchange** event. However **resize** can also get triggered by other things such as showing the virtual keyboard.

So to get round this we can listen first for an **orientationchange**, once that occurs we can then add a **resize** listener. Once the **orientationchange** has completed it will fire our **resize** event. Once completed we then remove the resize listener to prevent it being fired in error

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
    var orientationChange = function(evt) {
        rotateScreen();
        $(window).off('resize', orientationChange);
    }
    $(window).on('resize', orientationChange);
});
```

This effectively creates a kind of pseudo post:orientationChange event. (I would probably avoid using timeouts if you can)

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.