# clientWidth and innerWidth not updating on iOS Chrome after orientationchange

Tags: javascript, html, ios, google-chrome

The device I am testing with is iPhone 11, on Chrome version 87.0.4280.77. I have found out that after rotating your device, both`document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `window.innerWidth` are incorrect. Sometimes it lags behind, sometimes it outputs values that are smaller or greater than either one of your phone's dimension. Often both the `clientWidth` and `innerWidth` displays the same incorrect information, but at times they can be different. *I have also tested Safari, Firefox, Edge, and Opera, but they all came out correctly.*

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```js
const displayInfo = () => document.querySelector('.display-info').innerText = `clientWidth: ${document.documentElement.clientWidth}; innerWidth: ${window.innerWidth};`
displayInfo()

const handler = () => {
  const afterOrientationChange = () => {
    displayInfo()
    window.removeEventListener('resize', afterOrientationChange)
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', afterOrientationChange)
}
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handler)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="display-info"></p>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```

For instance, my phone's initial dimension should be 414 and 800. Here's what happens when I keep on rotating my phone back and forth (starting with portrait, rotating once after each result):

1. clientWidth: 414; innerWidth: 414;
2. clientWidth: 414; innerWidth: 414;
3. clientWidth: 318; innerWidth: 318;
4. clientWidth: 896; innerWidth: 896;
5. clientWidth: 318; innerWidth: 318;
6. clientWidth: 896; innerWidth: 318;
7. clientWidth: 318; innerWidth: 318;
8. clientWidth: 896; innerWidth: 896;

and so on.

Is this a known problem? Is there any way to work around this? It affects my CSS as well as it sometimes renders the website incorrectly.

Comment: Will it help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44484547/screen-width-screen-height-not-updating-after-screen-rotation

Comment: My issue is not the Javascript readings or event detections, but that the CSS also uses the wrong screen widths.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issues with Chrome on iOS. Have you find a workaround or fix? Thx