# Not able to get exact height/width of window on orientationchange without using resize and timeout

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm not able to get exact height/width of the window on orientation change. And it is working fine when I'm using resizing.

It is working fine in JQuery previous versions but it causing an issue on JQuery latest version.

Some condition: I don't want to use this with timeout

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(){
    alert($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mobile viewport height after orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452349/mobile-viewport-height-after-orientation-change)

Comment: Yes, the question is almost same but the solution they have shared to us is possible only with timeout  and I don't wanted to use timeout